# How to overwrite a parameter in Jenkins job

Tags: shell, jenkins, environment-variables

I'm trying to overwrite a parameter in a jenkins job.

my parameter looks like :

[image]

I have to execute a shell script to make the version look like **0.2.4** instead of 00.02.04

my shell script :

```
version=$1

convert_version () { 
IFS='.' read -ra ADDR <<< "$version"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
  version_c+=.$(($i))
done
version_c=${version_c:1}
export VERSION=$version_c
echo $version_c
}

convert_version
echo $VERSION
```

I added a pre-step to overwrite the VERISON env variable, but this is not working and when I'm executing printenv the VERSION has always the first value.

[image]

do you have any idea how to overwrite the parameter ?

Comment: there is a spelling mistake VERISON vs VERSION.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the EnvInject Plugin